# Is it possible to export the data from select query output or table to the excel file stored in your local directory

Tags: google-bigquery

I got this from user guide :
bq --location=US extract 'mydataset.mytable' gs://example-bucket/myfile.csv

But I want to export the data to the file located in my local path
example : /home/rahul/myfile.csv

When I am trying I got the below error:
Extract URI must start with "gs://"

Is it possible to export in local directory?

Also, Can we export the result of our select query to the excel?
Example : 
bq --location=US extract 'select * from mydataset.mytable' /home/abc/myfile.csv

Answer (score 0):

No, the BigQuery `extract` operation takes data out from BigQuery into a Google Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket.

Once data is in GCS you can copy it to your local system with `gsutil` or any other tool that might combine both operations.